# What books do you recommend on graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math, problem-solving, book-recommendation

I am recently coming across a lot of questions relating to graph theory, one of them is the following:

Given a simple graph G with n vertices. One edge e of G is called edgy, if the vertices of G can be split up into to subtotals A and B such that there are at most 100 edges with one end in A and one end in B and one of these is e. Prove that G has at most 100n edgy edges.

I looked for graph theory books on google and these books came up:

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=graph+theory+book

I am looking for books containing graph theory used in IMO's, so that I can learn the theory required for such questions. Could you please suggest some books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the simple side, but I've always liked Oystein Ore, Graphs and their Uses, Anneli Lax New mathematical library.

Answer (score 3):

Graph theory with applications
Book by John Adrian Bondy And Murty

Is the best graph theory book you can come across in my opinion. It just offers everything you need to know about graphs.